# Parse.com Query for future date

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, nsdate

I would like to query Parse.com and look for events in the future. Currently I am getting every object then comparing the date from the Parse.com object with Todays date in the app and display only the future events. This means that it is running slowly. I was wondering how I should compare the dates in the query.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PFQuery](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey:greaterThan:) provides all of the inequality operators (greaterThan, lessThan, greaterThanOrEqualTo, lessThanOrEqualTo), so the future looks like:

```
[query whereKey:@"myDateCol" greaterThan:[NSDate date]];
```